# Getting the latest Int 2 values of a constantly changing Integer

Tags: java, android, integer

I'm trying to check values in a constantly changing speed integer, The values I want to check is the current value and the one prior to it, I have this code, but it's not working for some reason.
My question is how can I efficiently save the latest 2 values of the constantly changing Speed integer

**Here's my code**

```
 int CurrentValue; // The Integer is already defined and initialized, this is the latest value of it
 int PriorValue; // this value is the one that was prior to the current one
 CurrentValue = ChangingInt; // here we save the current Speed value in ChangingInt

 if (CurrentValue != ChangingInt){
     PriorValue = CurrentValue; /* replacing the CurrentValue value as the prior one
     since it has changed according to the if statement */
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a `temp` variable to store the value of `CurrentValue`.

```
int CurrentValue;
int PriorValue;
int temp = CurrentValue; //Add a temp variable to store CurrentValue.
CurrentValue = ChangingInt;        
PriorValue = temp;
```

Comment: So I need to utilize a temporary value of the current one? and then make it equal to the prior one? but if that is the case then the all the values will be always the same since `temp = CurrentValue` then `PriorValue = temp`, isn't it the equivalent of doing `PriorValue = CurrentValue` since it's the same values?

Comment: Let's run an example. Let's say `CurrentValue = 1, PriorValue = 2`. Now a new `ChangingInt = 3` value is coming in, we then have `temp =  CurrentValue = 1, CurrentValue = ChangingInt = 3, PriorValue  = temp = 1`. So finally we get `CurrentValue  = 3, PriorValue  = 1`. Right?

Comment: According to your logic, when `CurrentValue = 1, PriorValue = 2`, and a new `ChangingInt = 3` value is coming in, then you will get `CurrentValue = ChangingInt = 3`, and `CurrentValue != ChangingInt` is always `false`!

Comment: Ah, I Understand, But I didn't initialize the value of `CurrentValue`, at the first run, will the first time run of this code perform a NullPointerException Error? or can i just wrap `int temp = CurrentValue;` in an if statement to solve the issue

Comment: You have two options here: use `Integer` instead of `int` because `null` is allowable for `Integer`; or initialize `CurrentValue` to some value like `0` or `-1`.

Comment: Oh Okay, Thank you, your answer is amazing

Answer (score 0):

```
int ChangingInt = ...          // ChangingInt = A, PriorValue = B, CurrentValue = C
...
int PriorValue = CurrentValue  // ChangingInt = A, PriorValue = C, CurrentValue = C
int CurrentValue = ChangingInt // ChangingInt = A, PriorValue = B, CurrentValue = A
```

We won't need `PriorValue` after this runs because we only need the last two values, so we should reassign `PriorValue` first by changing it to `CurrentValue` (because `CurrentValue` needs to become the new `PriorValue`). Then, we can change `CurrentValue` to `ChangingInt`.